# Share TFS project via email

Tags: tfs, share

I have my project in TFS that is located on visualstudio.com. But now I need to share it to few users only by only email and they do not have Microsoft account. Is it possible to get somethink like share link or read only priviliges link.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they need to [create a Microsoft Account](https://signup.live.com/). Though they can create an account for their existing email address (so that they don't get a new email account to go with it).